# Hide blanks cells XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have the following input XML:

figure2
        
      
      
        Support
        
        
      
      
        Support
        
        
      
      
        Support

I need to hide the PARTNUMBER column if the Table element has any column with "SPECIALMATERIAL" in its Class attribute; Secondly, I need to insert a new row just after the"figure" tag row. In this case new row should come at 2nd position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that does this (if I understood you request correctly):

```
<xsl:template match="table">
  <xsl:for-each select="row[cell/@class = 'SPECIALMATERIAL']">
    <tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="cell[normalize-space(.)]">
      <th><xsl:value-of select="."/></th>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>    
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```